# How Do I retrieve the content of a database into more than one model in MVC5?

Tags: database, model

I would appreciate your assistance on this challenge i'm having with retrieving the content of a database into more than one model. Three columns needed (InsBranchNo, PercentageCover and Leadcode) are available in Underwriting_InsurerPolicyDistribution table. However,  Account_ClientReceiptDistribution needs the content of these 3 columns for calculation. How do I pass the content of the 1st to the second for a particular Id using the Foreach Loop.

While retrieving the data from the database for a particular ID, below is how I loaded the rows involved into the  Model.Underwriting_InsurerPolicyDistribution model. 
My problem is. How do i transfer these rows into Model.Account_ClientReceiptDistribution model?

Your assistance is anticipated and will be very much appreciated.

//Policy distribution
    
        
            
                
                    
                        
                            ×
                            Insurer Risk Apportionment

---

---

Insurer Branch Code
                                            Is Lead Insurer
                                            Covered %
                                        
                                    
                                    @{if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Underwriting_PolicyFile.PolicyRefCode))
                                    {
                                        for (var i = 1; i <= Model.Underwriting_InsurerPolicyDistribution.Count; i++)
                                        {
                                            
                                                
                                                    @{var n7 = string.Format("Underwriting_InsurerPolicyDistribution[X{0}].InsBranchCode", i);}
                                                    @{var n8 = string.Format("Underwriting_InsurerPolicyDistribution[X{0}].InsuerLeadCode", i);}
                                                    @{var n9 = string.Format("Underwriting_InsurerPolicyDistribution[X{0}].PercentageCover", i);}

```
                                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Underwriting_InsurerPolicyDistribution[i - 1].InsBranchCode, new SelectList(Html.InsurerBranchDropDownList(), "InsBranchCode", "FullDescription", Model.Underwriting_InsurerPolicyDistribution[i - 1].InsBranchCode), new { id = n7, @class = "form-control input-sm" })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Underwriting_InsurerPolicyDistribution[i - 1].InsBranchCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Underwriting_InsurerPolicyDistribution[i - 1].InsuerLeadCode, new { id = n8, @class = "form-control input-sm" })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Underwriting_InsurerPolicyDistribution[i - 1].InsuerLeadCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Underwriting_InsurerPolicyDistribution[i - 1].PercentageCover, new { id = n9, @class = "form-control input-sm" })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Underwriting_InsurerPolicyDistribution[i - 1].PercentageCover, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                             </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    }
                                }
                                }

                              </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                         <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use select new model by linq, and define value of field based on the content values of the **Underwriting_InsurerPolicyDistribution**

```
var result = entityToEdit.Underwriting_InsurerPolicyDistribution.Select(a => new 
Account_ClientReceiptDistribution { 
                                    InsBranchCode = a.InsBranchCode, 
                                    PercentageCover = a.PercentageCover, 
                                    InsuerLeadCode = a.InsuerLeadCode 
                               }).ToList();


//pass the result into the model as shown in the line of code below

entityToEdit.Account_ClientReceiptDistribution = result;
```

I hope this will help someone out there.